# Speeding up Ajax success DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using an AJAX call on my page which return table rows and on success adds them to a table in the page. Below is the code currently used:

```
function GetDPRecords(Perso) {
        //alert(Perso);
        $Records = $('#DPRecords');

        //alert($PersoFileName.val()+" | "+$ProcFromDate.val()+" | "+$ProcToDate.val());
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "SelectDPRecords.jsp",
            data: $('form#Search_Form').serialize() + "&Personalized=" + Perso,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $Records.find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                $("<tr><td colspan='4'><h3 style='margin: 4px 10px'> Loading... </h3></td></tr>").hide().appendTo($Records).show(400);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $Records.find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                $(data).hide().appendTo($Records).show(400);
            }
        });
    }
```

The issue is that I at times expect a large number of rows to be returned (1,000-5,000). I did a test run with 4,000 rows data returned and it caused the browser to be unresponsive for about 20 seconds.

Any way to optimize the code and reduce the loading time?

Comment: Have you tried `$Records.empty()` or `$Records.find('tbody').empty()`?

Comment: `$(data).hide()` Seems odd.

Comment: Have you considered returning JSON so the JavaScript can manage large data sets as needed instead of tons of markup and hope the browser is able to parse it efficiently?

Comment: I wonder how behaves $(date).hide() could you replace that part with $Records.append(data) and see what it gives ? 20 seconds seems very long for markup insertion, there might be a loop somewhere in what you've written.

Comment: The loop is in the servlet handling the response. But that part shouldn't hang the browser right? (It's 'A'JAX) - @Sukima Can you please help me with how JSON would help.. as DOM manipulation would still take the time it would have instead adding more parsing/conversion from JSON -> HTML ?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use a paging system: instead of returning 1,000-5,000 rows, you break the results into pages of, say, 50 results each, and only return one page at a time. You would then give the user buttons to load other pages at the top/bottom of the table.

For an example of what I am talking about, see http://luis-almeida.github.io/jPages/defaults.html. It uses pictures instead of rows, but it is the same basic concept.

Comment: Have definitely thought of pagination.. but will have to see how it fits in with my current response servlet (need to make change there? or only in the client code part)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add @aj_r's suggestion If you do not want to hit the server again to retrieve the data for next range then you can store the result to a javascript variable (JSON Object Array) and then use that locally with pagination.

Comment: That seems a much preferred option. Is it possible to do it with my response as DOM instead of changing to JSON?

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing the same problem recently using huge datagrids in jqGrid and I've been able to find a tricky solution which turned out to be working very well.

Thing is you cannot render all this data at once - this is just too much, especially considering how slow DOM manipulations are. So you need some sort of queue. You can split this data into chunks and render them sequentiali using `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` but those doesn't have well reputation in terms of performance as well.

I ended up using reuestAnimationFrame and splitting my huge data into pieces and rendering them whenever an animation frame was available. So you need to start with polyfill to make sure what you are going to do will actually work, I'm using a great one by Paul irish:

Heres an awsome jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cjw5eota/1/

And here's the JS:

```
var dataRows = 5000; // enter ammount of returned rows
var chunkSize = 200; // define single chunk size, optimize for best performance bu trying different values, if your DOM manipulation is heavy use less, if its lightweight you can use more, use 1 to see in slowmo how it works

// We are simulating big returned object here
var data = {}
for (var i = 0; i < dataRows; i++) {
    data[i] = {
        'id': i,
        'name': 'I am data for row ' + i
    };
}

// shim layer with setTimeout fallback
window.requestAnimFrame = (function () {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || function (callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();

function renderRecords(data) {
    var dataLength = Object.keys(data).length;
    var i = 0;

    function renderInQueue() {
        console.time('Rendering in queue');
        for (t = 0; t < chunkSize; t++) {
            if (i < dataLength) {
                var row = '<tr><td>' + data[i].id +
                    '</td><td>' + data[i].name + '</td></tr>'
                $('table').append(row);
            }
            i++;
        }

        if (i < dataLength) {
            requestAnimationFrame(renderInQueue);
        } else {
            console.log('Done rendering');
            console.timeEnd('Rendering in queue');
        }
    }

    renderInQueue();
}

// run the script of rendering
renderRecords(data);
```

I have included a simple performance benchmark for you to see in console how much an entire rendering process takes. Play with `chunkSize` to see how it changes and try to find a value that will best suit your needs, that is give you decent rendering time without putting heavy load on the browser.

The more you try to render at once the fastest the rendering will be, but more resources will be required to handle each iteration of rendering.

Comment: Thanks bro, but `requestAnimationFrame` would not work with IE8, which unfortunately for me needs to be supported. Can you show how I can do without it (hot to use simple `setInterval()/setTimeOut()`)

Comment: Thanks to the polyfill this will work in IE8 as well and it will fallback to `window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60)`. Look closely in the code (part after the comment "// shim layer with setTimeout fallback") plus try running the fiddle in IE8 if you can.

Comment: Oh right. Will check. Just one thing..  Here the data is plot up in a map whole in my case it's one big case of DOM...  So I assume I will have to alter my servlet returned data..  Any way (modification to this code perhaps) which won't require me to the servlet?

Comment: Hi - i modified the code to reflect the format of my returned data..But, it's not working as expected... please help - http://jsfiddle.net/fo51wxzj/1/